# What Emacs package should I install for command-line on FreeBSD?

Tags: command-line-interface, freebsd

I'm newbie on BSD.

I installed FreeBSD with minimal configuration, so there's no package installed.
I tried `pkg_add -r emacs`, the command tried installing many of X11 related packages (not sure, but it look like). There are so many ports on BSD ports website, so I'm confusing what's suitable for me.

I'm looking for a light-weight Emac with command-line interface. I'm trying to use command-line only environment. So GUI is not an option.

Comment: What version of FreeBSD? Are you sure it was installing X11 and not just some of the Xlibraries that Emacs requires?

Comment: `$ pkg_add -r vim-lite` /me ducks ;)

Comment: @Jed I'm not sure it was X11 or not, but it look like X11 packages. So many packages. I'm sorry for this. And I don't think Emacs requires any X11 related library packages. BSD version is 8.1

Comment: @ErikA, vi is included in the base system. Real men use `vi`. @Eonil, Emacs can be built for X11 or without; see my answer for the without version.

Comment: @ChrisS Now it's years ago, and you were right. I ditched emacs and took `vi`. Real men use `vi`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under the old *pkgtools* system: You want `pkg_add -r emacs-nox11`
For the newer *pkgng* system: You want `pkg install emacs-nox11`

Comment: Updated with both options